# Spring cloud microservice server port cast exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Being new to spring boot and microservices architectures, trying to build a simple app using spring boot cloud starter.

I've used `spring-cloud-config-server` in order to externalize config files (.properties)

I've got here the spring cloud config which brings .properties files from a git repository and **another microservice** `(product-microservice)` trying to reach its config from the `spring-cloud-config-server` microservice.

Everything works fine, except for the `server.port` property which **throws** a `ClassCastException` (inside the 2nd microservice)

Here's the config file:
https://github.com/mssm199996/microservice-ecommerce-2/blob/master/product-microservice.properties

**Code about the 1st microservice:**

```
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class CloudServerConfigApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CloudServerConfigApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mssmfactory</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloud-server-config</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cloud-server-config</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

---

```
server.port=8888
spring.application.name=config-server

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/mssm199996/microservice-ecommerce-2.git
```

---

**Code about the 2nd microservice:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mproduits</groupId>
    <artifactId>mproduits</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>mproduits</name>
    <description>Microservice de gestion des produits</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ********************************************************************** -->

        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

---

```
spring.application.name=product-microservice
```

---

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START *********************
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Failed to bind properties under 'server.port' to java.lang.Integer:
>
> ```
> Property: server.port
> Value: {value=9091, origin=1:15}
> Origin: "server.port" from property source "bootstrapProperties"
> Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>] to type [java.lang.Integer]
> ```
>
> Action:
>
> Update your application's configuration

Comment: Looks like you have two properties, one of them is bootstrap.properties that has a configuration class with `@ConfigurationProperties("someclass")` annotation then you try to get a map of LinkedHashMap and Integer, but you should declare a map of String and Integer.

Comment: Not at all x) ... I've a @ConfigurationProperties("com.mssmfactory"), but trying to get  the com.mssm.productsFetchSize=4 which is inside the file that i shared its github url, into an integer property that's all

Comment: could you please post your  class which has `@ConfigurationProperties`?

Comment: Yeah of course, here's the link to the class => https://github.com/mssm199996/microservice-ecommerce-2/blob/master/microservice-products/src/main/java/com/mproducts/config/PropertiesHolder.java

Comment: Yeah, I understood what is the issue, when you try to have `server.port=x` from config server then you were not able to get them because you get first bootstrap.application that is loaded before starts the application. then you need to add a setting to override the config properties you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem.

It was an issue in the `pom.xml` file, because i've **downloaded** the above microservice from a **github repository** and it was using an **old version** of **spring** that **i modified without modifying the spring cloud version** which **conflicts** with the **newer version**
of spring.

What i did was, **creating a new module in intellij** using `spring intializr` and adding **spring cloud config client** dependancy to it so that it **generates** automaticaly the `pom.xml` file, and **used** it in my microservice.

here's the new pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mproduits</groupId>
    <artifactId>mproduits</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>mproduits</name>
    <description>Microservice de gestion des produits</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.M3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ********************************************************************** -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

You need to override your properties which are sent from `config server`, then add in `product-microservice.properties` the following configurations:

```
spring.cloud.config.allowOverride=true
spring.cloud.config.overrideNone=false
spring.cloud.config.overrideSystemProperties=false
```